# Absoluted positioned links on an image are not clickable

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm stucked with a problem with z-index and stacking context. I created link absoluted positioned on a image but the links aren't clickable. If I remove `position:relative;z-index:-10` in the first rule in the code my problem is resolved but in this way comes broken an other component, a menu that overlaps, and would fall under if you lifted this rule. Thus not eliminating that rule in the main, how can I resolve the problem?
(In my code there are a lot of simplifications in some parts)

```css
main[role='main'] {
  position: relative;
  /*These two rules need to avoid that when menu open is under*/
  z-index: -10;
}

#presentation-hashfood img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slide-show {
  position: relative;
}

.presentation-hashfood-title {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  top: 24%;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.presentation-hashfood-title svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: var(--colore-secondo);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.presentation-hashfood-title text {
  fill: var(--colore-quarto);
}

.hashfood-span-1 {}

.hashfood-span-2 {
  font-size: 35.6px;
}

@supports (mix-blend-mode: screen) {
  .presentation-hashfood-title {
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
  }
  /* text tag svg che imposto a nero per sovrascrivere la fallback */
  .presentation-hashfood-title text {
    fill: #000;
  }
}

.slide-show-left-arrow,
.slide-show-right-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  border: .5px solid whitesmoke;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px;
  ;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f5f5f5e5;
}

.slide-show-left-arrow {
  left: 2%;
}

.slide-show-right-arrow {
  right: 2%;
}

.slide-show-left-arrow::before {
  content: 'g';
}

.slide-show-right-arrow::before {
  content: 'h';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="prova.css">
</head>
<body>
   <main role='main'>
      <section id='presentation-hashfood'>
           
         <header>
            <div class='slide-show'>
            <h2 class="presentation-hashfood-title">
               <!-- Questo codice svg serve per ottenere il typographic lock-up, una tecnica che permette al contenuto di entrare perfettamente nel suo box -->
               <svg viewBox="0 0 345 60" role="presentation">
                  <text id="presentation-hashfood-title-textcontent">
                    <!-- Put both tspan elements on same line, to prevent bug in WebKit. -->
                    <tspan class="hashfood-span-1" x="3" dy="0.8em">#FOOD IL N°1 IN ITALIA</tspan> <tspan class="hashfood-span-2" x="3" dy="0.9em">NEL FOOD DELIVERY</tspan>
                  </text>
                </svg>
                
            </h2>

            
            <picture>
               <source media="(min-width:50em)" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/fqQ4tNh/img.jpg"> <!-- immagine da 1200px -->
               <source media="(min-width:37.5em)" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/fqQ4tNh/img.jpg"> <!-- immagine da 800px -->
               <source media="(min-width:25em)" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/fqQ4tNh/img.jpg"> <!-- immagine da 600px -->
               <source  srcset="https://i.ibb.co/fqQ4tNh/img.jpg"> <!-- immagine da 400px -->
               <img src='https://i.ibb.co/fqQ4tNh/img.jpg' title='Hashfood n° 1 in Italia' alt='Immagine Hashfood n° 1 in Italia'> <!-- immagine da 800px come fallback -->
            </picture>

            <a href='index.html' class='slide-show-left-arrow' aria-label='Freccia per scorrere le immagini indietro'></a>
            <a href='#' class='slide-show-right-arrow' aria-label='Freccia per scorrere le immagini avanti'></a>
         </div>
         </header> 

      </section>
      
   </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Simply removing `z-index` on `main` should solve the issue; it doesn't distort the display (at least in the code provided). Alternatively you could just set a higher `z-index` on the desired links.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I have already tried to set hight z-index on the desired link and it doesn't work.    And how I wrote I can't remove z-index on the `main` because otherwise I have serious problems with an other component of the code (a menu that will overlap the image). Thus How could I resolve?

Comment: You haven't included any code that has problems when you remove the `z-index`. What are the "*serious problems with an other component of the code*"? Please include those in the question, or else we can't help solve your issue.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I have resolved. I had omitted the other code because was long and it was difficult to recreate a minimum working code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `z-index: -10;` from the `.main[role='main']`.

*Check it in action on Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/abBZKpo*

```css
main[role='main'] {
  position: relative;
}

#presentation-hashfood img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slide-show {
  position: relative;
}

.presentation-hashfood-title {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  top: 24%;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.presentation-hashfood-title svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: var(--colore-secondo);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.presentation-hashfood-title text {
  fill: var(--colore-quarto);
}

.hashfood-span-1 {}

.hashfood-span-2 {
  font-size: 35.6px;
}

@supports (mix-blend-mode: screen) {
  .presentation-hashfood-title {
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
  }
  /* text tag svg che imposto a nero per sovrascrivere la fallback */
  .presentation-hashfood-title text {
    fill: #000;
  }
}

.slide-show-left-arrow,
.slide-show-right-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  border: .5px solid whitesmoke;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px;
  ;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f5f5f5e5;
}

.slide-show-left-arrow {
  left: 2%;
}

.slide-show-right-arrow {
  right: 2%;
}

.slide-show-left-arrow::before {
  content: 'g';
}

.slide-show-right-arrow::before {
  content: 'h';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="prova.css">
</head>
<body>
   <main role='main'>
      <section id='presentation-hashfood'>
           
         <header>
            <div class='slide-show'>
            <h2 class="presentation-hashfood-title">
               <!-- Questo codice svg serve per ottenere il typographic lock-up, una tecnica che permette al contenuto di entrare perfettamente nel suo box -->
               <svg viewBox="0 0 345 60" role="presentation">
                  <text id="presentation-hashfood-title-textcontent">
                    <!-- Put both tspan elements on same line, to prevent bug in WebKit. -->
                    <tspan class="hashfood-span-1" x="3" dy="0.8em">#FOOD IL N°1 IN ITALIA</tspan> <tspan class="hashfood-span-2" x="3" dy="0.9em">NEL FOOD DELIVERY</tspan>
                  </text>
                </svg>
                
            </h2>

            
            <picture>
               <source media="(min-width:50em)" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/fqQ4tNh/img.jpg"> <!-- immagine da 1200px -->
               <source media="(min-width:37.5em)" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/fqQ4tNh/img.jpg"> <!-- immagine da 800px -->
               <source media="(min-width:25em)" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/fqQ4tNh/img.jpg"> <!-- immagine da 600px -->
               <source  srcset="https://i.ibb.co/fqQ4tNh/img.jpg"> <!-- immagine da 400px -->
               <img src='https://i.ibb.co/fqQ4tNh/img.jpg' title='Hashfood n° 1 in Italia' alt='Immagine Hashfood n° 1 in Italia'> <!-- immagine da 800px come fallback -->
            </picture>

            <a href='index.html' class='slide-show-left-arrow' aria-label='Freccia per scorrere le immagini indietro'></a>
            <a href='#' class='slide-show-right-arrow' aria-label='Freccia per scorrere le immagini avanti'></a>
         </div>
         </header> 

      </section>
      
   </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because is the best that resolve my described problem though adjusting it like that I had other problems in the code that I resolved whit the aid of others than I thank.

Answer (score 1):

So you will still need to remove the z-index you've got here, and to make sure the menu will go on top of this make sure the menu has a position that isn't static (i.e. relative, absolute, etc.).  Then you should be able to increase that menu's z-index to keep it above the slideshow.

Comment: I had already tried this too. And it works but inside the menu there is another absoluted positioned link (the X to close the menu) that in this way remain visible when I close the menu

Comment: @Umbert are you sure the `X` close menu is inside the menu container in that case? Because if the container of the menu is toggled with `display: none`, all of it's element inside should be hidden as well, you say the `X` close menu remain visible means it's outside the menu container

Comment: @Kyojimaru You have centered the problem. I toggled the `X` close menu visibility changing the z-index from -1 to 1. Instead now changing the  display property to hide it obviously it works.  God bless you.

Comment: @Umbert I think it's better for you to update some of your markup if the `menu` and `close button` should not be separated, rather than you have `<div id='menu'>...</div><btn id='btn-close'>` in separate container, it's better to be in 1 container together `<div id='menu-container'><div id='menu'>...</div><btn id='btn-close'></div>` or something like that, so you can just toggle `display` for `menu-container` rather than doing it separately for `menu` and `btn-close`.